# add description to each enum value for swagger-UI documentation

Tags: java, swagger-ui

How can I add some description to each enum value for swagger-UI documentation?

My EnumClass:

```
@ApiModel
public enum EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation {
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_1(1), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_2(2), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_3(3), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_4(4), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_5(5), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_6(6), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_7(7);

    private int numVal;

    EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation(int numVal) {
        this.numVal = numVal;
    }

    public int getNumVal() {
        return numVal;
    }
}
```

The model

```
private EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation carrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation;

// getter setter......
```

I would like to add some description to `CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_1`.

I tried

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "blabla2")
CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_1(1), //
```

but that is not working.

Swagger-UI output:

```
carrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation (string, optional) = ['CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_1', 'CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_2', 'CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_3', 'CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_4', 'CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_5', 'CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_6', 'CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_7']
string
Enum:   "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_1", "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_2", "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_3", "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_4", "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_5", "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_6", "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_7"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: why don't you use a descriptive name for the enum, instead of "CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_7"?

Comment: Some description are like: "Presubscribed carrier exists,   
and carrier is not input by
calling party. Presubscribed
carrier is used." for e.g. value 1 and "Presubscribed carrier is same as
carrier input by calling party.
Input carrier is used." for value 2, ...


It's a bit hard (for me :S ) to find a  descriptive name. The description is for Swagger-UI, for documentation. ...and I just see that my title is not hinted at Swagger-UI

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Enum {

public enum EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation {
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_1(1,"ONE"), //
    CARRIER_SELECTION_SUBSTITUTION_INFORMATION_2(2,"TWO"),

        private final int value;
        private final String description;

        EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation(int value, String desc){
            this.value = value;
            this.description = desc;
        }
        public int value(){
            return this.value;
        }
        public String description(){
            return this.description;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation elem: EnumCarrierSelectionSubstitutionInformation.values()){
            System.out.println(elem + "value is "+ new Integer(elem.value()) + " desc is " + elem.description());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ho does this answer the question for swagger-UI documentation?